# how to check that I could send email?

Tags: python, email

I want to check that I can send email from my python program. Unfortunately it failed and it looks to me because SMTP server does not accept my call.
I just need to check that my program correct and I could send email ... but I failed to check it.
Here's my program and how could I make server to accept my call?

```
import smtplib

# Here are the email package modules we'll need
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

COMMASPACE = ', '

# Create the container (outer) email message.
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Our family reunion'
me = "susja@gmail.com"
family = "dusja@gmail.com"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(family)
msg.preamble = 'Our family reunion'


# Send the email via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
s.sendmail(me, family, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I've got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "2.py", line 21, in <module>
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 249, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 309, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 284, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 562, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: did you try to create a connection with port 587, so `smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 21, in <module>
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 249, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 309, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 284, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Comment: if I add port 587 I have this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 22, in <module>
    s.sendmail(me, family, msg.as_string())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 722, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, '5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. e4sm2329031qar.12 - gsmtp', 'susja@gmail.com')

Comment: Indeed, you will need to call `s.starttls()` and right after that, additionally I would also expect to see an `s.login(user, password)` call before invoking `sendmail`.

Comment: well, I did this way:
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
s.starttls()
s.login('susja@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
s.sendmail(me, recepient, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
and got this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\ipython\ipython\Lib\smtplib.py", line 302, in connect
  File "\Scripts\sendEmail_Expl.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\ipython\ipython\Lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
  File "c:\ipython\ipython\Lib\smtplib.py", line 277, in _get_socket
socket.error: getaddrinfo returns an empty list
It looks it doesn't like either credentials or etc ...

Comment: If your user name is not the same as your e-mail address, did you try calling `login` with your actual user name i.s.o. e-mail?

Comment: For username I used my email.  I also tried to use username without @gmail.com but got the same result

Comment: - Erik,
Thanks so much!!!. After I provided port, email and password I was able to send it. Appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I will post this as the answer to make sure other people can find it easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things appear to be missing in the code sequence above:

- you need to use port 587
- a call to `starttls()` is needed to switch to the SSL/TLS protocol
- you need to login to the Gmail SMTP server by calling `login` with your gmail username and password.

The last section of your code should now look like this:

```
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
s.starttls()
s.login('gmail_username', 'gmail_password')
s.sendmail(me, family, msg.as_string())
s.close()
```

Comment: For me I was missing `s.starttls()` and 
`s.login('gmail_username', 'gmail_password')`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who runs into a similar problem with AWS and Flask, the solution I found was to set the environment variable `MAIL_USE_TLS=True`.  Again this is only for flask.ext.mail, but it may save someone some time and effort in the future.